# Can I use `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` in my commercial software source?

Tags: c, open-source, gpl

Can I use the crypt() function in my commercial software source?

if I want to use crypt() I have to add

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

that's why I m asking this question.
Can I use `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` in  my commercial software source?

Comment: Surely that `#define` related to the fact that `crypt()` is part of [X/Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open), not because it can only be used in apps covered by an open source licence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.

`_XOPEN_SOURCE` has absolutely nothing to do with [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software). It simply indicates that you desire to use the interfaces defined by [X/Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open), specifically in the X/Open Portability Guide. And those interfaces don't restrict license of your software; after all, [X/Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open) consortium included several important commercial companies.